# Unable to install Oracle

Tags: windows-7, installation

I have installed Oracle few months back. I was running fine in my local system. Unfortunately my friend has removed all the directories in safe mode. Meaning to say it was not properly uninstalled from my system. I tried to remove all the Registry keys, Services associated with Oracle.

Now, I can install it. However I am unable to use any sqlplus services or anything. How do I completely remove my hidden old files and services if any. Need to install and use it.

Comment: Was it a server install or just a client and which version?

Answer (score 3):

- Install a virtualization software like Virtualbox or VMware
- Install a new instance of Windows 7
- After installation, use `regedit` and export your registry; and also export your path
- Install Oracle
- Export registry once more
- Check what differences have been made in registry and path
- Use this information to undo changes made in your real Windows system
- Tell your friend to stay the hell away from your computer if he doesn't know what he's doing

Comment: I would give +10 for the last point if I could.